# Сортировка html-таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется скрипт http://jsfiddle.net/akwvcmvd/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    sortTable();
})

function sortTable(){
      var rows = $('#mytable tbody tr.iedit');

      rows.sort(function(a, b) {
          var A = +$(a).find('.rating').text().match(/\b[\d]+\b/)[0];
          var B = +$(b).find('.rating').text().match(/\b[\d]+\b/)[0];

          if(A < B) {
            return -1;
          }

          if(A > B) {
            return 1;
          }

          return 0;

      });

      $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
      });
}
```

HTML

```
<table name="mytable" id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='iedit'>
            <td>value7</td><td class="rating">rating = 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='iedit'>
            <td>value1</td><td class="rating">rating = 60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='iedit'>
            <td>value4</td><td class="rating">rating = 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='iedit'>
            <td>value1</td><td class="rating">rating = 2</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Как видите тут две колонки. Нужно сделать рейтинговую таблицу. Нужно чтобы в 1 колонке приписывалось МЕСТО в рейтинге. На примере вышеуказанного скрипта. Нужно чтобы независимо от значения 2 колонки, в 1 были номера т.е. МЕСТА в рейтинговой таблицы. Как мне добиться цели? Надеюсь я смог объяснить суть вопроса. Если нет, то постараюсь объяснить еще подробнее. **Дико извиняюсь** за название темы ибо я реально не смог подобрать короткое объяснение своего вопроса. **Заранее спасибо за ответы!**

Comment: То есть вместо вместо value1, value4, value7, value1 (при верной сортировке по рейтингу порядок строк первой колонки из примера будет такой) должно быть 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: Да. Именно. Спасибо что поняли так как нужно!

Comment: Судя по ответу уважаемого Serge Esmanovich, я могу прийти к выводу что я недостаточно объяснил. Постараюсь по другому... Я делаю рейтинговую таблицу (ТОП-чарт).  <tr> будут выдываться  CMS. То есть это будет своего рода динамичная таблица. Добавил пункт в CMS, а она отобразилась в таблице в соответствующем месте исходя из числа, которое я укажу при добавлении в CMS. Все пункту будут иметь это число. Чем больше это число, тем он выше в таблице. Каждому пункту внутри CMS будет выдаваться это число. Скрипт который я указал в вопросе, умеет сортировать эти числа которые я выдам, но скрипт меняет и

Comment: и содержание первой колонки, а у меня (так как рейтинговая таблица) место (то есть первая колонка) должна оставаться неизменной. И еще немаловажная соль в том, что при добавлении пункта в своей CMS, в таблице должно добавится еще одно место. Покажу на картинах. http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/15/1221/h_1450707679_8950925_5ef789ae1a.png  это первое. http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/15/1221/h_1450707679_3414293_ad24977118.png это второе. Линиями указал на изменения.

Comment: @midagent так мой вариант самое то, могу переделать под эту табличку на скрине

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich В вашей табличке Руслану уже присвоено 1 место,   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Руслан</td>
    <td>62</td>
  </tr> То есть если общий балл Максима поменять с 56 скажем на 78 (больше чем у Руслана), то Максим должен занят 1 место. 1 место не в положении в таблице, а по значению в 1 колонке. В вашей табличке Руслан с 1 местом просто поднимается вверх по таблице.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Есть идея посредством JS посчитать сколько <TR> есть в таблице. Дальше скрипт который указал в вопросе сортирует по значению общего балла, а потом посредством JS пронумеровать <TR>. Правда это как алгоритм, а в JS я полный ноль, поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Гляньте пожалуйста комментарии ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var test = [];
  $('tr').each(function(){
    test[$(this).find('td:last-child').text()] = $(this);
  });
 console.log(test);
  $('table tr').remove();
  var key = 1;
  $.each(test,function(index,item){
   // console.log(item);
    if(item){
     item.find('td:first-child').text(key);
    $('table').append('<tr>'+item.html()+'</tr>');
      key++;
    }
  });  
});
```

http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/GoqNQP

На самом деле я немного пошутил =) 
так будет чутка правильней

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var objects = [];
      $('tr').each(function(){
     var   value = $(this).find('td:last-child').text();
      var  item =  $(this);
        objects.push({value:value,item:item});
      });
      objects.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
      // Сортировка по возрастанию
      return obj1.value-obj2.value;
  // Сортировка по убыванию
  return obj2.value-obj1.value;
    });
     console.log(objects);

      $('table tr').remove();

      $.each(objects,function(index,item){

        if(item.item){
         item.item.find('td:first-child').text(index+1);
        $('table').append('<tr>'+item.item.html()+'</tr>');

        } 
      });   
    });
```

Comment: К сожалению вы меня не так поняли. Прочитайте пожалуйста комментарии выше, я объяснил подробнее. Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: @midagent Добавил счётчик

Comment: спасибо! примерно это я и хотел. Только тут есть две недоработки. Во второй я виноват сам, извиняюсь. А первая. Если добавить два <TR> с одинаковым общим баллом, в таблице появляется только последняя добавленная. А вторая то что сортировка общего балла идет на возрастание, хотелось бы на убывание.

Comment: я надеюсь, что вы поможете это исправить?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы чем БОЛЬШЕ общий балл, тем ВЫШЕ место. Могли бы помочь?

Comment: @midagent  // Сортировка по убыванию return obj2.value-obj1.value;

Comment: Спасибо мил человек! Век не забуду вас) Не удаляйте страницу в кодпен) Завтра использую)